# how can get integer json value in secondary layout (end of recycler view)

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

this is my json :

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 10,
  "count_total": 65,
  "pages": 7,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 3115,
      "type": "post",
.
.
.
}]}
```

want get pages value end of my recycler view :
[image]

this is my AsyncTask function to get json :

```
 if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                        int id=jsonObj.getInt("pages");


                        JSONArray posts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                            jsonContent jsonContent=new jsonContent();

                            jsonContent.title=c.getString("title");

                            //img
                           JSONObject post_img=c.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            for (int j=0;j<post_img.length();j++)
                            {
                                JSONObject v=post_img.getJSONObject("mom-portfolio-two");
                                jsonContent.imgurl=v.getString("url");
                            }
                            jsonContent.pages=id;
                            listcontent.add(jsonContent);

                        }
```

and this is my adapter :

```
  public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
        List<jsonContent> jcontent;



        public DataAdapter(Context context,List<jsonContent> jcontent) {

            this.context=context;
            this.jcontent=jcontent;

        }



        @Override
        public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

           View view ;
            if(i == R.layout.card_row) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
            }else {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.button_card, viewGroup, false);
            }
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder,int i) {


            if(i == jcontent.size()) {
                viewHolder.buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                viewHolder.buttonprev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "pre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });

                viewHolder.pages.setText(Integer.toString(jcontent.get(i).pages));

            }
            else {

                viewHolder.title.setText(jcontent.get(i).title);

                Picasso.with(context).load(jcontent.get(i).imgurl).resize(300, 400).into(viewHolder.imageView);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
                return jcontent.size()+1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return (position == jcontent.size()) ? R.layout.button_card : R.layout.card_row;
        }


        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            private TextView title,pages;

            private ImageView imageView;

            private Button buttonnext,buttonprev;

            private CardView cardView;


            public ViewHolder(final View view) {
                super(view);


               title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
                imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                buttonnext =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.next);
                buttonprev=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.prev);
                cardView=(CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cvv);

                pages=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.number_pages);
    }
    }
    }
```

but when launch app and scroll down to end of recycler view when become to to end of recycler app crash and got this error :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 10
```

from this line :

```
 viewHolder.pages.setText(Integer.toString(jcontent.get(i).pages));
```

and pages is my text view for show pages int value in secondary layount end of recycler view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your List jcontent size is 10 (0 to 9).
Check this line in onBindViewHolder

```
if(i == jcontent.size()){ //here i == 10

 .......
 .......
 viewHolder.pages.setText(Integer.toString(jcontent.get(i).pages));
 //here you are accessing the 10 element of jcontent.
}
```

Comment: so how can i fix that ?

Comment: if you want to retrieve number of pages simply do jcontent.get(i - 1).pages) for i == 10.

Answer (score 2):

I found a  snippet from your code

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return jcontent.size()+1;
    }
```

change that to

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return jcontent.size();
    }
```

its beacouse the list counting start from **0** not from **1**

if you are try to get **10** from list of 10 size. it will throw array out of bound exception.

You should get 9 to get the 10th element.

```
if(i == jcontent.size()) {
            viewHolder.buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            viewHolder.buttonprev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "pre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            viewHolder.pages.setText(Integer.toString(jcontent.get(i).pages));

        }
        else {

            viewHolder.title.setText(jcontent.get(i).title);

            Picasso.with(context).load(jcontent.get(i).imgurl).resize(300, 400).into(viewHolder.imageView);

        }
    }
```

in this code you are getting **jcontent.get(i)** this will make problem

---

EDIT 2

---

It seems **Pages** is constant for every recycler item, then extract it from main JSON object and pass as separate thing, or take it from any other object,

like

```
  if(jcontent.size()>0){
      pages =jcontent.get(0).pages;
      viewHolder.pages.setText
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: think you do not understand my point correctly . if i do that my recycler view dont show my secondary layout end of recycler . and is not my point

Comment: change like what ? i do this :  viewHolder.pages.setText(Integer.toString(jcontent.pages)); but cant recognize pages when remove get(i)

Comment: Actually what are you trying to achieve? If your json object only contains 10 elements , what are you displaying at 11th page without any details?

Comment: i told my issue clear in my question . and when i remove this line  viewHolder.pages.setText(Integer.toString(jcontent.pages)); my app well and show 10cardview + my secondary layout

Comment: And the secondary layout you are taking  jcontent.get(i) . There is no element with that reference . if you are not executing this line, your code is absolutly perfect

Comment: know that . but i post my issue here for get correct answer . if you want help me and accepted your answer give me some way to solve my issue not suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131145/discussion-between-erfan-and-godwin).

Comment: come in chat please